# Indy Server Delphi 7 in Eclipse Juno

Tags: java, android, eclipse, delphi, delphi-7

I want to build a proxy/http server in Eclipse for Android. I dont know how to do that.

My question is - how to build an Android app that is similar to an Indy Server in Delphi 7?

Comment: Delphi 7 does not support Android development, you need Delphi XE6 or later for that. I think the OP is asking how to write an HTTP server *in Eclipse* that acts *like* an Indy server in Delphi 7.

Comment: thanks Remy.... yeah i know dephi 7 not suport android  dev. i just want to know how to create http proxy server android app with ecipse not dephi xe cause my pc system desnt run perecty 4 dephi xe its lag as hell